# Can ἐρισθενέος mean "almighty"?

Tags: ancient-greek, greek-translation

Someone claims that ἐρισθενέος Κρονίωνος (line 4 of Hesiod's Theogony) means "the almighty son of Cronos" as part of his argument that the ancients believed Zeus was the One (related [question](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/10555/whats-with-this-religion-of-zeus-being-one-and-only-omnipotent-god)).

But the Loeb translates it as "Cronus' mighty son"; Liddel & Scott's gives the definition: "very mighty"; Bailly gives "trés fort, trés puissant"; Frisk's etymological dictionary defines the prefix ἐρι- as "sehr, hoch".

Google shows a few results with "most mighty; all-powerful", for [example](https://homeric_el_en.en-academic.com/3994/%E1%BC%90%CF%81%CE%B9%CF%83%CE%B8%CE%B5%CE%BD%CE%AE%CF%82). I'm not sure if those definitions are being too loose or it does mean all-powerful or almighty.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

σθένος, the second part of the compound, clearly does mean 'strength, power' (it mainly shows up in compounds, as in ἀσθενής 'weak'), but ἐρι- is a rare old prefix that barely shows up in Classical Greek; it's mostly limited to words in Epic Greek and godly epithets, many of which are opaque.
Going purely by etymology, by comparison with Hittite *šēr* we would indeed expect it to have meant 'high' originally (as in ἐριαύχην 'with high-arching neck (of horses)') and from there turned into 'very' (ἐρίτιμος 'highly prized', ἐρίδματος 'strongly built'). In a lot of divine epithets it's obscure, though: ἐριβρεμέτης is pretty transparently 'high-thundering' (Zeus), ἐριούνης could be 'very helpful' (Hermes), but ἐρίσφηλος is completely unknown (Heracles).

ἐρισθενής itself shows up [nine times](https://anastrophe.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/perseus/search3torth?dbname=GreekNov21&word=lemma%3A%E1%BC%90%CF%81%CE%B9%CF%83%CE%B8%CE%B5%CE%BD%CE%AE%CF%82&OUTPUT=conc&ORTHMODE=ORG) in the entire Perseus corpus: twice in Hesiod, four times in Homer, twice in the *Argonautica*, and once in the *Aethiopica*. In Homer and Hesiod it's always an epithet of Zeus, in the *Aethiopica* of fate, and in the *Argonautica* it's used of mortal men both times; clearly it wasn't understood to mean 'all-powerful' by Apollonius Rhodius, at least.

While it's impossible to tell what Hesiod and the Homers themselves thought ἐρισθενέος meant exactly, like Apollonius Rhodius I see no reason to see it as anything but 'very mighty'. 'Almighty' is just a looser literary translation, not an accurate one.